# ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.stop) Could not fetch resource

Tags: command-line-interface, gcloud, google-cloud-platform

I want to stop a vm instance running on a particular project. I use

**gcloud compute instances stop**

I can stop a instance for a project. But when i change the current project to another project, i cant stop the instance running using the same command. Its showing the error,

**gcloud compute instances stop instance-1-2**

**ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.start) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/myproject/zones/asia-southeast1-a/instances/instance-1-2' was not found**

I set the project using :
**gcloud compute set project projectname**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run the command **gcloud compute instances stop** ,
it will stop the instances in the zone which you had already set.

You can set the zone using : **gcloud config set compute/zone ZONE**

and region using : **gcloud config set compute/region REGION**

where ZONE=zone which you want to assign and 
REGION=region you want to assign

For the above scenario , do :

**gcloud config set compute/zone ZONE_OF_instance-1-2**

then

**gcloud compute instance stop instance-1-2**

Refer: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/#set_default_zone_and_region_in_your_local_client

Answer (score 4):

When you run

```
gcloud compute instances stop instance-1-2
```

this command is underscpecified, `instance-1-2` is lacks project and zone. Since that was not specified on command line project (and zone) is deduced from properties.

Note that the command to set project property is NOT `gcloud compute set project projectname`, but `gcloud config set project projectname`.

If you want this command to work regardless of property settings you can use full path to resource

```
gcloud compute instances stop projects/projectname/zones/asia-southeast1-a/instances/instance-1-2
```

Or use command line flags

```
gcloud compute instances stop instance-1-2 --project projectname --zone asia-southeast1-a
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to stop or start multiple instances regardless of the zone they are located in and had the same error.
my solution was to create a tag and run the following command with the sub-command output that returns the format of `projects/<project-name>/zones/<zone>/instances/<instance-name>`

**Stop multiple instances by tag**

```bash
gcloud compute instances stop $(gcloud compute instances list --project ${PROJECT} --filter="tags.items=(autoshutdown)"  --format="value(selfLink.scope(v1))") --project ${PROJECT}
```

**Start multiple instances by tag**

```bash
gcloud compute instances start $(gcloud compute instances list --project ${PROJECT} --filter="tags.items=(autoshutdown)"  --format="value(selfLink.scope(v1))") --project ${PROJECT}
```